# Transition effect is not working properly

Tags: css

Transition doesn't work, I want to achieve the smooth effect on scroll. I'm using the JS script below, the script is working. However, CSS transition is not.

Any help is appreciated!

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 550 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 550) {
    document.getElementById("header").style.height = "70px";
    document.getElementById('classic-logo').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('minifyed-logo').style.display = "block";

  } else {
    document.getElementById("header").style.height = "100px";
    document.getElementById('minifyed-logo').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('classic-logo').style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <!-- Content -->
</header>
```

Comment: Weird choice by Paulie D; the "duplicate" question is not particularly helpful for addressing the problem in this question.  This question should probably closed for a different reason, though, so I won't vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a second property to transition, in this case `height`.

```js
window.onscroll = scrollFunction;

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 550 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 550) {
    document.getElementById("header").style.height = "70px";
    document.getElementById('classic-logo').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('minifyed-logo').style.display = "block";

  } else {
    document.getElementById("header").style.height = "100px";
    document.getElementById('minifyed-logo').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('classic-logo').style.display = "block";
  }
}

scrollFunction();
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 1000px;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  transition: 0.3s height;

  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div id="classic-logo">Classic</div>
  <div id="minifyed-logo">Minifyed</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which properties to transition on:

```
#header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}
```